Angular this(local) getting Undefined when moving to next step in MultiStepForm causing error on required fields
I'm working on production where I've to develop the MultiStep-form. For each Step, I have separate forms and  the last three forms are are FormArray (eg :experiences could've of multiple) here the initialize.
    this.experienceForm = this.fb.group({
      Experiences: this.fb.array([this.CreateExperience()])
    })

     CreateExperience(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      Organization: ['', Validators.required],
      Designation: ['', Validators.required],
      Department: ['', Validators.required],
      FromDate: ['', Validators.required],
      ToDate: ['', Validators.required],
      StartingSalary: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(0)]],
      EndingSalary: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(0)]],
      address: [''],
      leavingReason: [''],
    });
  }

But when I navigate to the next Step the fields which are required show an error message. After debugging, I found that this was undefined, which cause this block to get executed.
 <div *ngIf="experience.get('StartingSalary')?.hasError('required')" class="text-danger m-2">
                  Starting Salary is required
                </div>

When this is undefined, both condition become undefined eventually leads to true.
I've tried to use different ways especially making sure that all the fields of experience are NOT markAllAsTouched(). Apart from this, is nothing coming to my mind.
